# XAML Element Alignment issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a list view that will contain notes that I input. I am having trouble figuring out how to have the list view item look how I want it to.

Below is how it should look:

[image]

And this is what it currently looks like:

[image]

How do I write the list view item in XAML so that the Date and time appear to the very top-right of each list view item, with the text of the note to the left?

```
<ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Note}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
    <DataTemplate>
        <ListViewItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Any help at all is much appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you add a screenshot of what your screen currently looks like as well, for comparison purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a number of elements required in order to get your screen to look the way you want.

- You need to define the `ItemTemplate` for the `ListView`. You're on the right track here, it is a `DataTemplate` declared in XAML, you just have to apply it to the ListView.ItemTemplate property.
- You need to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` of the `ListView` to Stretch (the default is Left, which means your items will not fill the entire content area).
- You need to use a `DockPanel` (or other similar panel) inside your `DataTemplate` to place your date content on the right, and the remainder of your content on the left.
- You need to disable Horizontal Scrolling (`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisbility`) on the `ListView` in order to make your content wrap (otherwise it will just happily draw it all on one line).

I've included a sample ListView that should get you started.

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock 
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                    Text="{Binding Date}" 
                    Background="Magenta" 
                    DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Background="Lime" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks @Todd, regarding "Disable HorizontalScrollBarVisibility", it still draws it on one whole line anyway. Any idea how I can wrap the `Content` text?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about TextWrapping. Sigh. This is what happens to my brain when I go on Holidays. I forget the simple things!